# Magento 2 reserved_order_id not equal to increment_id

Tags: increment-id

We are running a Magento 2.3.6 store and since a few weeks we are having a very strange problem: For some orders the reserved_order_id in the quote table seems to be not transferred correctly to the sales_order table, so in these cases we have two different order ids for the same order! This is quite serious because the reserved_order_id is sent to the customer in the order confirmation email and also to our ERP system, but in the Magento backend the order cannot be found because the increment_id is not equal to the reserved_order_id generated in quote.

Another strange thing is that this doesn't happen with all orders, just with some of them, but I can't find any pattern when the problem occurs and when not.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this inconsistency? And what I should check in this case?
I really hope that anyone here could help or lead me in the right direction!

Comment: What are the payment modules you are using? Is the issue happen for specific payment methods? or check if any other module reserving the order ids.

Comment: We are using the Open Payment Platform (Credit/Debit Card) module, but the issue happens for different payment methods, also i.e. for payment in advance. I really cannot find any pattern when it happens, not dependent on store or guest/non-guest or payment method. And sorry to ask - but how can I check which modules are reserving order ids? Unfortunately I overtook the management of the shop, so I was not envolved right from the start.

Comment: You may check the full code base for the function "reserveOrderId". Also, you may check this link [ https://mage2.pro/t/topic/583 ] to get an idea of how Magento handle, generate, and save reserveOrderId. If there will any incomplete order then the Order Id sequence may alter and such kind of issue may occur. It is hard to say what exact reason cause for the error of your project.